# Bash script to tar a folder saves basepath

Tags: bash

My script tars a folder in my /home/user directory and saves it all in a backup folder. However, when I open each of the tar.gz all of them have the directory /home/user and then the folders and files I wanted to compress.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ~/backup ]; then
    mkdir ~/backup
fi

for i in `ls ~/folder`; do
    echo "~/folder/$i"
    if [ -d ~/folder/$i ]; then
        tar -zcf ~/backup/$i.tar.gz ~/folder/$i
    fi
done
```

What can I do to prevent /home/user to be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to go inside to that folder. Something like:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d ~/backup ]; then
    mkdir ~/backup
fi

cd ~/folder

for i in *; do
    echo "~/folder/$i"
    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
        tar -zcf ~/backup/"$i".tar.gz "$i"
    fi
done
```

Also, is better to use quotes for variables when these variables refers to file names.

Comment: I was looking for a solution that wouldn't have the need to use `cd` but it seems like it is the only way. Anyway, thanks for your answer because I also had the issue with the spaces and this way fixes my problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong to use `cd`. After the `for` loop you can go back to the old directory if you need using `cd $OLDPWD`.